# ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)

Tags: python

Writing a decoding program and keep running into

> ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)

when I input the string I need to decode. The input string is:

```
[2ea^W_`^k2eiWSd2fZSf2[2S_2gb2fa2`a2YaaV@
```

The code is as follows currently:

```
# String manipulation
# This program accepts a string and an integer
# then decodes the number of lines by a know decryption key

# Initialize the program and necessary variable
print("This progam can decode an encrypted by a known encryption key")
string=""
decoded_message=""
coded_message=""

# Prompting the used for input using a for loop to accept multiple lines
coded_message=input("What is the line to be decoded?")

# Using a for loop, the messges will be decrypted character
# at at time to its ASCII value then decrypted and converted
# back to text
for string in coded_message:
    converted_text=ord(string)
    decryption=(chr(converted_text-18))
    decoded_message+=decryption
# Output the decoded message
print("Your decrypted message is:",decoded_message)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe when you subtract 18 from original ascii value, it goes out of range,i.e, less than 0.

Comment: Turns out this was the problem. The message we were being given to test had a space in it that was not supposed to be there.